# Fowarding Email to CRM Systems -- What's the advantage?

Tags: project-management, project, crm

I'm using Basecamp as a trial and Highrise as a trial and both offer the ability to cc emails from clients into the system.  I'm a web developer and usually my team is myself and one or two IC's, plus the client(s).  All of my email is very highly organized into client specific folders --- so at this point I'm trying to figure out what the advantage would be to have many of these email conversations (Between me and the client/between me and the ICs) online?  Whether it's a prospect in Highrise, or an ongoing project in Basecamp, what's the advantage of having the email in two places -- HR/BR and filed in my email folders?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [OpenCRM](http://opencrm.co.uk) we encourage the forwarding of all mail in and outbound to be polled by the CRM. Essentially this allows quick access to the complete history from the lead, contact, company, or other associated record such as a sales order, or helpdesk ticket, related to the originator or recipient of the message.

It's a good idea to work with [CRM Software](http://opencrm.co.uk/crm.html) that allows this level of integration, affording you to pick up and respond to messages while you're actively working on that particular record in your data. We feel this saves time and duplication of effort.